# Recognizing instructions containing low-level control flows

Tags: x86, control-flow-graph

There are some `x86` instructions which containing a low-level** control flow in its semantics, for example [div](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html) because its semantics is roughly as:

```
if (source == 0)
   throw exception...
else
   return rdx:rax / source
```

or instructions with `rep` prefix, etc. While a `mov` or a `xor` doesn't contain any control flow.

I am trying to classify instructions of `x86` ISA depending on this criteria, my starting point now is looking into [Xed](https://intelxed.github.io/)'s API to know if there exists some function which can give such an information, but it doesn't seem having any.

Concretely for `div`, I've checked [xed_decoded_inst_conditionally_writes_registers](https://intelxed.github.io/ref-manual/group__DEC.html#gad267d2d08e002b027915248689d1defe), [xed_operand_conditional_read/write](https://intelxed.github.io/ref-manual/group__DEC.html#gad6b80021a33c772fa74a038f17343562), but all of them return false.

** I'm sorry for this word, I don't know the precise terminology for this case.

Edit: many thanks for comments but I've badly expressed my question. I update in the following some discussion to make the context more clear.

Xed's API would not give full instruction semantics, but some. For example, with some xed API (which I described above) we can get:

```
mov rax, r8

operands:                       2
uses rflag:                     no
has conditional read operand:   no
has conditional write operand:  no
conditionally write register:   no
```

and

```
cmovb rax, r8

operands:                       3
uses rflag:                     yes
has conditional read operand:   no
has conditional write operand:  yes
conditionally write register:   yes
```

so at least I know that `cmovb` should have some conditional control flow in its semantics, while `mov` has not.

I tried to apply this logic for other instructions: it works for some (e.g. `rep movsb`, etc.), but not all:

- for `div`*** (or `mov`), it would be "acceptable"* to say that there is no
  conditional control flow, IMHO. We consider that an exception is side
  effect: the instruction is not executed (or only partially executed)
  if the exception is thrown
- for other cases of, e.g. `minps`, this logic simply doesn't work

*** I have initially thought that `div` contains conditional data-flow, but changed later :)

Comment: Not automated, but in the Intel manual for instructions there is information about when exceptions happen. See for example https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html

Comment: A `mov` or `xor` may alter control flow in the same way by triggering a page fault eception with invalid memory access.